# Weird focus() behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, setfocus, autofocus

My goal is to open an `input` element in a popup and focus that input.

So logically, I have tried `$('#input').focus()`, `$('#input').first().focus()`, and `$('#input')[0].focus()`, but they do not work; but when I change tab and come back to my tab the `input` element is in focus. Has anybody seen something similar? Or know how to explain this, or even better, know how to fix this...

P.S. For comments: yes, it is the only input with id "input" on my page, and yes I have an `input` element with id "input" on my page, and yes, code for focusing elements is called after the `input` has been added to the dom.

Comment: Calling `.focus()` from within some other event handler (like something that switches tabs) can be a problem. In my experience, you can solve it by wrapping the focus call in a timeout handler, with a very short timeout time. And `$("#input").focus()` is all you need (in the timeout handler).

Comment: P.P.S: and no you didn't have provided any MCVE  :)  But i guess Pointy is right. One more thing, hidden element cannot be focused, maybe that's more relevant then to focus it once shown

Comment: See also [Why is setTimeout(fn, 0) sometimes useful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful)

Comment: I have tried this with wrapping into timeout and nothing happens. Also it seems that is only related for my project. But I'm really interested to found out why input is in focus when i change tab and come back to my page or even when chrome lost focus.

Comment: @Grissom But in which context are you calling your snippet? Once the popup is loaded? Same behavour using `autofocus` attribute?

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes everything is loaded when i tried to focus it. autofocus does work but only first time when opening popup.

Comment: @Grissom We really need some link to check it. At least how do you call `$("#input").focus()`???

Comment: It start working, not sure how, it seems that was just issue with chrome, sorry everyone for bothering

Comment: change the name of the input the browser creates default ids for elements unless its been already taken

Answer (score 1):

```
window.load = function(){$("#input").focus();}
```

Basically `window.load` is the event which only fires when all elements of page are loaded.

You can add above code within page anywhere. Preferably at the last of page within `<script type="javascript"> </script>.` So after all elements are loaded, it will set focus to input field.

Comment: With explanation a good answer becomes a useful answer.

Comment: Basically windows.load is the event which only fires when all elements of page are loaded.

You can add above code within page anywhere. Preferably at the last of page within javascript script. So after all elements are loaded, it will set focus to input field.

Comment: I added your comment to the answer using the "edit" function. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

From my comment above, here's what I'm suggesting:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $("#input").focus();
}, 0);
```

That arrangement lets the current event thread finish, including any "native" actions the browser wants to perform. The timeout can then run in a context where the only change to the page state will be setting the focus.